# Хранение кода сайта в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование

Есть задание создать сайт, в условиях указано, что карта сайта должна храниться в БД. Что это означает? Хранение кода сайта в базе данных, а не в файлах? Как это осуществить?

Comment: Рискну предположить, что речь идет о [sitemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map)

Comment: Лучше уточнить это у того кто вам поставил это задание. Без контекста сложно сказать о чем идет речь.

Comment: Приведите задание полностью, т.к. все разговоры ниже ни о чем без конкретики задания...

Answer (score 2):

Нет, карта сайта - это аналог оглавления в книгах, когда на одной странице содержится множество ссылок на все все остальные разделы сайта. Не знаю, часто ли такими страницами пользуются живые пользователи, а вот ботам поисковиков такая страница существенно упрощает жизнь, позволяя с одной страницы попасть на остальные страницы сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Это означает, что те данные, которые необходимы для воспроизведения всех переходов между компонентами сайта должны храниться в БД, как их хранить - это уже как вам захочется

Comment: Можете подсказать, зачем хранить её в БД?

Comment: Спросите у того, кто выдал вам это задание, я не вижу никаких причин применять такой подход

Comment: @JuliaPominchuk чтобы можно было легко менять структуру сайта со страницы администрирования без вмешательства в исходный код сайта, например. Весьма часто встречается. Ну ио информации из БД можно собирать роботам ранее упоминавшийся sitemap (если, правда, не имелся в виду только он)